# How to search SQL Database and display it on a JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Just like what the title says, I want to search a SQL Database and display it on the JTable using a jTextField on `keyReleased`.
This is what I've tried:

```
 private void jTextField2KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        

 try{
     int get = (int)jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(jTable2.getSelectedRow(), 0);
        String query = "SELECT FName FROM roominfo WHERE FName LIKE '%" + jTextField2.getText() + "%'";

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adv"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","sa"); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
         jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    conn.close();

}
     catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }         // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

However, I can't do it properly. What seems to be the problem? It still doesn't search.

Comment: you are never calling `rs.next()`. Please read the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to hit the database every time a key is released? Please explain what you are trying to accomplish, and maybe we can offer a better/more correct solution

Comment: _Don't_ run a query on the EDT; _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: `keyReleased` is used to make it automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `keyPressed`:

```
try{
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adv"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","sa"); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT CustomerNo, FName, FROM roominfo WHERE FName LIKE '%" + jTextField2.getText() + "%'";
      rs = st.executeQuery(query);
      jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 

    conn.close();

}
     catch (Exception e) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Download rs2xml.jar library and import that into your particular project library.
Then `import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;` inside particular java class.
There is a database table called student, When we insert id value inside `txtId` and then click that created `search` button for action. The row data of particular student id will execute inside of created `tableStudent`.

code inside `search` button is below:

```
        String id = txtId.getText();
        String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id ='"+id+"'";
        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(searchQuery);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            tableStudent.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UpdateDonor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```